# How to derive odds-ratios and p-values to see if the difference is significant?

Tags: python, p-value, continuous

I have two different groups of samples: samples1 and samples2.

Moreover, I have 18 different elements and for each element, there is the corresponding score attained from using all samples of samples1 and samples2, respectively.

e.g.:

score_samples1[0] means the score for the first element attained by using all samples of samples1.

score_samples2[0] means the score for the first element attained by using all samples of samples2.

Now, I want to compare the difference between these two sample groups and find out whether this difference is statistically significant.
As shown below, I have applied a t-test to get a p-value to assess the significance.

My question is as follows:
Is there a way to derive odds-ratios and p-values to see if the difference is significant?

```
from scipy import stats
import statistics

score_samples1=[1.430442073, 1.347975371, 1.175088823, 1.20141693, 1.152665995, 1.105591463, 1.343297357, 1.251526193, 1.107442697, 1.302090741, 1.312426241, 1.24880381, 1.46855296, 1.12369795, 1.344426189, 1.24276685, 1.216269219, 1.172317535]
score_samples2=[1.663793448, 1.506660754, 1.387285644, 1.440433062, 1.367680224, 1.340102236, 1.632881551, 1.522894543, 1.137437101,1.581845495, 1.540401185, 1.549114159, 1.558038893, 1.392571495, 1.532717551, 1.451731862, 1.277597967, 1.336609308]

stats.ttest_ind(score_samples1,score_samples2)

stats.ttest_ind(score_samples1,score_samples2, equal_var=False)
Ttest_indResult(statistic=-5.03264933189511, pvalue=1.7512132919948795e-05)

#Paired t-test
stats.ttest_rel(score_samples1,score_samples2)
Ttest_relResult(statistic=-11.148411105604898, pvalue=3.0763665473016024e-09)
```

Assume that I categorize the scores as follows:

```
scores_ge_cutoff_samples1=[1 if x>=1.30 else 0 for x in score_samples1] 
scores_ge_cutoff_samples2=[1 if x>=1.30 else 0 for x in score_samples2]

scores_ge_cutoff_samples1
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]  
scores_ge_cutoff_samples2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

oddsratio, pvalue = stats.fisher_exact([[16, 2], [7, 11]])
pvalue
0.004510832141532924
oddsratio
12.571428571428571
```

Based on this analysis, we can conclude that samples2 having a score>=1.30 is 12.57 times more likely than samples1 having a score>=1.30.

However, I was aiming a get an odds ratio for the difference between samples1 and samples2 scores.

Comment: I don't follow how you would want to use regression to get the odds ratio: it's a direct computation from classification results.

Comment: @Prune Got it. Edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "an odds ratio for the difference ..."?

Comment: In all of the t-tests I got a p-value, can I also get an odds ratio?

Comment: Or is there a way to apply logistic regression and get an odds ratio through logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about experimental procedure.  "Is this significant" is not something you decide with some computation afterwards; it's a critical parameter of your experimental design.  You decide *before* you do the experiment, just what level of significance you'll accept as confirming the hypothesis you chose.

A one-tailed t-test requires a hypothesis that, say, sample 1 is greater than sample 2.
A two-tailed t-test requires a hypothesis that sample 1 and sample 2 are from different distributions -- but not which would be greater than the other, just that they're different.

Since you've done both tests, it appears that you failed to design your experiment at all.  For scientific integrity, you now have to start over, *design* your experiment, and re-run your samples.

On the other hand, you're in *very* good shape for a reasonable result.  Typical thresholds for a conclusion are a p-levels of 0.95, 0.98, and 0.99; these accept error rates of 5%, 2%, and 1%, respectively.

Your p-scores are *far* below even the most stringent of these (e-5 versus e-2), so you shouldn't have any trouble with that part.  The code is quite simple -- something such as this:

```
t_score, prob = stats.ttest_ind(score_samples1, score_samples2)
if prob <= 0.01:
    print("The hypothesis is confirmed")
else
    print("The hypothesis is not confirmed")
```

Comment: I'm more interested in computing the odds-ratio, since I already got the p-value. How can I compute odds-ratio? Can regression be a way to do it? if yes, how?

Comment: Odds ratio applies to classification examples, not continuous distributions (such as you presented).  If you want help with OR, you'll have to present an applicable case.

Comment: What if I make the following:                                                                                           >>> scores_ge_1_30_samples1=[1 if x>=1.30 else 0  for x in score_samples1]
>>> scores_ge_1_30_samples2=[1 if x>=1.30 else 0  for x in score_samples2]
>>> scores_ge_1_30_samples1
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> scores_ge_1_30_samples2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]                                                                      Then how to use regression to provide odds-ratio?

Comment: Please refer to the posting guidelines.  If you have significant amendment to your question, it belongs in the question.  Comments do not handle code well, and *cannot* render Python code accurately.